# I want to to store content in database with an emogi  but it shows error

Tags: sql

I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[22007]:** Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '**\xF0\x9F\x99\x82** (...' for column 'content' at row 1

Comment: mention your RDBMS and sample text, your datatype and input details

Comment: Updating the question with your `query` would be easy to get answers

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Database: Change Database default collation as utf8mb4.

2) Table: Change table collation as CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin.

Query:

```
ALTER TABLE Tablename CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_bin
```

Code:

```
INSERT INTO tablename (column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6, column7)
VALUES ('273', '3', 'Hdhdhdhhzhzhzzhjzj 我爱你 ❌', 49, 1, '2016-09-13 08:02:29', '2016-09-13 08:02:29')
```

4) Set utf8mb4 in database connection:

```
 $database_connection = new mysqli($server, $user, $password, $database_name); 
 $database_connection->set_charset('utf8mb4');
```